# Display name store in struct C

Tags: c, function, struct

How can I display name that was previously stored in struct in another function?

Example :

```
typedef struct
{
 char name[10];
}n;

void info()
{
  n play;
  printf("Enter name  : ");
  scanf("%s", &play.name);
}
```

How do I display the name in 'welcome' function?

```
void welcome()
{

 printf("Hi %s have a nice day!", ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a pointer to a `n` struct into the `info()` function and update it. Then pass that `n` into the `welcome()` function:

```
void info(n *play)
{
    printf("Enter name  : ");
    scanf("%s", &play->name);
}

void welcome(n play)
{
    printf("Hi %s have a nice day!\n", play.name);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    n play;
    info(&play);
    welcome(play);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you read the value in your `info` function and therefore, in your `welcome` function it is out of scope, as `play` was defined inside `info`. You could return an `n` from `info` and use that value.